# Why aren't props being passed to a child component in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Why aren't the props being passed to the component in `InventorySectionGroupItemComponent`

https://codesandbox.io/s/cgvbc

?

There's a warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.   
found in        
---> <InventorySectionGroupItemComponent>    
       <InventorySectionGroupComponent> at /src/components/InventorySectionGroupC.vue    
         <InventorySectionComponent> at /src/components/InventorySectionC.vue    
           <ChromePage> at /src/components/ChromePage.vue    
             <App> at /src/App.vue    
               <Root>
```

vue hates long component names (correct me if I'm wrong)(Updated sandbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component name has nothing to do with the error. The problem is [`InventorySectionGroupC.vue` incorrectly registers `VueGridLayout`](https://codesandbox.io/s/cgvbc?file=/src/components/InventorySectionGroupC.vue:619-638):

```js
import VueGridLayout from 'vue-grid-layout';

export default {
  name: "InventorySectionGroupComponent",
  components: {
    VueGridLayout, // incorrect registration
  },
}
```

[`vue-grid-layout`'s installation guide](https://jbaysolutions.github.io/vue-grid-layout/guide/#installation) shows how to register the components:

```js
import VueGridLayout from 'vue-grid-layout'

export default {
  components: {
    GridLayout: VueGridLayout.GridLayout,
    GridItem: VueGridLayout.GridItem,
  }
}
```

As a side note, `grid-layout` and `grid-item` are actually used in `InventorySectionC.vue`
(not `InventorySectionGroupC.vue`), so their component registration should be moved into that component.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-vue-grid-layout-usage-3lh8g?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Forrgot to fork but managed to fix it (my guess was that it was related to the length of the component name).